# How to pass url parameters from a controller in Angular to a php

Tags: php, angularjs

I need to send a URL with this format to a php file.

```
"http://localhost/project/api.php?id="+$scope.idProd+"&price="+$scope.priceProd
```

Can I do it with $http.post? I have tried to do

```
$http.post("http://localhost/project/api.phpid="+$scope.idProd+"&price="+$scope.priceProd)      
.success(function(res){
                  console.log(res);
});
```

My php not received correctly this url and displays the following errors: **Undefined index: id and Undefined index: price**

Comment: You should be using AngularJs Resource: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Answer (score 1):

Those are url-encoded params.  You do it like this:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    //function to serialize data to url-encoded data
    transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
    },
    //the data you're passing
    data: {id: $scope.idProd, price: $scope.priceProd}
}).success(function () {});
```

Comment: This code works fine for me, thank you I really appreciate your help.